# Unable to attach or mount volumes: unmounted volumes=[data], unattached volumes: timed out waiting for the condition

Tags: kubernetes, rabbitmq, kubernetes-helm, kubernetes-pvc

Getting error while installing rabbitmq using helm

> Unable to attach or mount volumes: unmounted volumes=[data], unattached volumes=[kube-api-access-jmx28 configuration data]: timed out waiting for the condition

Hi

Getting error while installing rabbitmq using helm

> Unable to attach or mount volumes: unmounted volumes=[data], unattached volumes=[kube-api-access-jmx28 configuration data]: timed out waiting for the condition

I have tried installing rabbitmq using below commands

```
/usr/local/bin/helm repo add bitnami https://charts.bitnami.com/bitnami
/usr/local/bin/helm install rabbitmq bitnami/rabbitmq --namespace rabbitmq --create-namespace
```

After installing above commands, It created below statefulset script

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: StatefulSet
metadata:
  annotations:
    meta.helm.sh/release-name: my-release
    meta.helm.sh/release-namespace: rabbitmq
  creationTimestamp: "2023-08-16T15:58:53Z"
  generation: 1
  labels:
    app.kubernetes.io/instance: my-release
    app.kubernetes.io/managed-by: Helm
    app.kubernetes.io/name: rabbitmq
    helm.sh/chart: rabbitmq-12.0.10
  name: my-release-rabbitmq
  namespace: rabbitmq
  resourceVersion: "43954838"
  uid: 6f44f692-09a1-4863-a8ed-ca55db349cbb
spec:
  podManagementPolicy: OrderedReady
  replicas: 1
  revisionHistoryLimit: 10
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app.kubernetes.io/instance: my-release
      app.kubernetes.io/name: rabbitmq
  serviceName: my-release-rabbitmq-headless
  template:
    metadata:
      annotations:
        checksum/config: 16a6077e795d2f93f818a08278a424989dd1a1d670ee13b8c64990c428302596
        checksum/secret: d768f8a948cef5ba937a53823b03e07d9c3a1414e7a310a345095ecfe3a14d62
      creationTimestamp: null
      labels:
        app.kubernetes.io/instance: my-release
        app.kubernetes.io/managed-by: Helm
        app.kubernetes.io/name: rabbitmq
        helm.sh/chart: rabbitmq-12.0.10
    spec:
      affinity:
        podAntiAffinity:
          preferredDuringSchedulingIgnoredDuringExecution:
          - podAffinityTerm:
              labelSelector:
                matchLabels:
                  app.kubernetes.io/instance: my-release
                  app.kubernetes.io/name: rabbitmq
              topologyKey: kubernetes.io/hostname
            weight: 1
      containers:
      - env:
        - name: BITNAMI_DEBUG
          value: "false"
        - name: MY_POD_IP
          valueFrom:
            fieldRef:
              apiVersion: v1
              fieldPath: status.podIP
        - name: MY_POD_NAME
          valueFrom:
            fieldRef:
              apiVersion: v1
              fieldPath: metadata.name
        - name: MY_POD_NAMESPACE
          valueFrom:
            fieldRef:
              apiVersion: v1
              fieldPath: metadata.namespace
        - name: K8S_SERVICE_NAME
          value: my-release-rabbitmq-headless
        - name: K8S_ADDRESS_TYPE
          value: hostname
        - name: RABBITMQ_FORCE_BOOT
          value: "no"
        - name: RABBITMQ_NODE_NAME
          value: rabbit@$(MY_POD_NAME).$(K8S_SERVICE_NAME).$(MY_POD_NAMESPACE).svc.cluster.local
        - name: K8S_HOSTNAME_SUFFIX
          value: .$(K8S_SERVICE_NAME).$(MY_POD_NAMESPACE).svc.cluster.local
        - name: RABBITMQ_MNESIA_DIR
          value: /bitnami/rabbitmq/mnesia/$(RABBITMQ_NODE_NAME)
        - name: RABBITMQ_LDAP_ENABLE
          value: "no"
        - name: RABBITMQ_LOGS
          value: '-'
        - name: RABBITMQ_ULIMIT_NOFILES
          value: "65536"
        - name: RABBITMQ_USE_LONGNAME
          value: "true"
        - name: RABBITMQ_ERL_COOKIE
          valueFrom:
            secretKeyRef:
              key: rabbitmq-erlang-cookie
              name: my-release-rabbitmq
        - name: RABBITMQ_LOAD_DEFINITIONS
          value: "no"
        - name: RABBITMQ_DEFINITIONS_FILE
          value: /app/load_definition.json
        - name: RABBITMQ_SECURE_PASSWORD
          value: "yes"
        - name: RABBITMQ_USERNAME
          value: user
        - name: RABBITMQ_PASSWORD
          valueFrom:
            secretKeyRef:
              key: rabbitmq-password
              name: my-release-rabbitmq
        - name: RABBITMQ_PLUGINS
          value: rabbitmq_management, rabbitmq_peer_discovery_k8s, rabbitmq_auth_backend_ldap
        image: docker.io/bitnami/rabbitmq:3.12.2-debian-11-r8
        imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
        lifecycle:
          preStop:
            exec:
              command:
              - /bin/bash
              - -ec
              - |
                if [[ -f /opt/bitnami/scripts/rabbitmq/nodeshutdown.sh ]]; then
                    /opt/bitnami/scripts/rabbitmq/nodeshutdown.sh -t "120" -d "false"
                else
                    rabbitmqctl stop_app
                fi
        livenessProbe:
          exec:
            command:
            - sh
            - -ec
            - curl -f --user user:$RABBITMQ_PASSWORD 127.0.0.1:15672/api/health/checks/virtual-hosts
          failureThreshold: 6
          initialDelaySeconds: 120
          periodSeconds: 30
          successThreshold: 1
          timeoutSeconds: 20
        name: rabbitmq
        ports:
        - containerPort: 5672
          name: amqp
          protocol: TCP
        - containerPort: 25672
          name: dist
          protocol: TCP
        - containerPort: 15672
          name: stats
          protocol: TCP
        - containerPort: 4369
          name: epmd
          protocol: TCP
        readinessProbe:
          exec:
            command:
            - sh
            - -ec
            - curl -f --user user:$RABBITMQ_PASSWORD 127.0.0.1:15672/api/health/checks/local-alarms
          failureThreshold: 3
          initialDelaySeconds: 10
          periodSeconds: 30
          successThreshold: 1
          timeoutSeconds: 20
        resources: {}
        securityContext:
          runAsNonRoot: true
          runAsUser: 1001
        terminationMessagePath: /dev/termination-log
        terminationMessagePolicy: File
        volumeMounts:
        - mountPath: /bitnami/rabbitmq/conf
          name: configuration
        - mountPath: /bitnami/rabbitmq/mnesia
          name: data
      dnsPolicy: ClusterFirst
      restartPolicy: Always
      schedulerName: default-scheduler
      securityContext:
        fsGroup: 1001
      serviceAccount: my-release-rabbitmq
      serviceAccountName: my-release-rabbitmq
      terminationGracePeriodSeconds: 120
      volumes:
      - name: configuration
        projected:
          defaultMode: 420
          sources:
          - secret:
              name: my-release-rabbitmq-config
  updateStrategy:
    type: RollingUpdate
  volumeClaimTemplates:
  - apiVersion: v1
    kind: PersistentVolumeClaim
    metadata:
      creationTimestamp: null
      labels:
        app.kubernetes.io/instance: my-release
        app.kubernetes.io/name: rabbitmq
      name: data
    spec:
      accessModes:
      - ReadWriteOnce
      resources:
        requests:
          storage: 8Gi
      volumeMode: Filesystem
```

--> When i use below command, it is displaying below output with pending state

[root@ip-182-36-45-49 ~]# kubectl get all -n rabbitmq NAME
NAME                        READY   STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE
pod/my-release-rabbitmq-0   0/1     Pending   0          46m

```
NAME                                   TYPE        CLUSTER-IP      EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)                                 AGE
service/my-release-rabbitmq            ClusterIP   10.111.96.235   <none>        5672/TCP,4369/TCP,25672/TCP,15672/TCP   46m
service/my-release-rabbitmq-headless   ClusterIP   None            <none>        4369/TCP,5672/TCP,25672/TCP,15672/TCP   46m

NAME                                   READY   AGE
statefulset.apps/my-release-rabbitmq   0/1     46m
```

--> I have created PV and Storage class using below script. When i describe Node, It is displaying below output

```
kind: PersistentVolume
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  name: ebs-pv
spec:
  capacity:
    storage: 20Gi
  volumeMode: Filesystem
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteOnce
  persistentVolumeReclaimPolicy: Retain
  storageClassName: ebs-sc
  awsElasticBlockStore:
    volumeID: vol-0hdfgrtjh7ern989d
    fsType: xfs

---
apiVersion: storage.k8s.io/v1
kind: StorageClass
metadata:
  name: ebs-sc
provisioner: kubernetes.io/aws-ebs
```

--> kubectl describe pod/my-rabbitmq-0 -n rabbitmq

> Events:
> Type     Reason            Age                  From               Message
>
> ---
>
> Warning  FailedScheduling  19m (x5 over 27m)    default-scheduler  0/6 nodes are available: pod has unbound immediate PersistentVolumeClaims. preemption: 0/6 nodes are available: 6 No preemption victims found for incoming pod..
> Normal   Scheduled         19m                  default-scheduler  Successfully assigned rabbitmq/my-rabbitmq-0 to ip-172-31-9-220.us-east-2.compute.internal
> Warning  FailedMount       12m                  kubelet            Unable to attach or mount volumes: unmounted volumes=[data], unattached volumes=[kube-api-access-w7qzm configuration data]: timed out waiting for the condition
> Warning  FailedMount       3m46s (x2 over 15m)  kubelet            Unable to attach or mount volumes: unmounted volumes=[data], unattached volumes=[data kube-api-access-w7qzm configuration]: timed out waiting for the condition
> Warning  FailedMount       90s (x5 over 17m)    kubelet            Unable to attach or mount volumes: unmounted volumes=[data], unattached volumes=[configuration data kube-api-access-w7qzm]: timed out waiting for the condition

How to solve above error, Can anyone please help me on this

Comment: did you happen to solve this?i see a similar issue